# Download video in website which block Inspect Element

Tags: macos, safari, safari-web-inspector

I want to download video from url: http://tvhai.org/xem-phim-hoac-nguyen-giap-2006-383757

However, when I searched video link in Inspect Element, this website blocked all video information. Therefore, I can't find the streaming link (m3u8 link).

My question is how to download video on this website?
Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the overlay div.

The video link is: https://rr4---sn-5goeen7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1631207185&ei=kc45Ydv1FdSE-LYP8PKoiA0&ip=2402:1f00:8000:2ad::&id=ef0bbe59bf59748b&itag=18&source=blogger&susc=bl&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&dur=30.069&lmt=1627873139135654&txp=1311224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,susc,mime,vprv,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgFjlrvt7umncIrXH-GIcY0CgHsIvqksPfvSSPPJOt-UcCIF-ZP6EQG7_48C1gP77llfCAqZ2JdJ2ySq8CLwd7XCIF&rm=sn-apaapm4g-apae7l,sn-npo6z7z&req_id=1c7015be57b5a3ee&redirect_counter=2&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mh=O0&mip=62.243.28.42&mm=29&mn=sn-5goeen7d&ms=rdu&mt=1631189567&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=24&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgL3X8HSsVWAoA9BEbpSfuzz6Yp3B_FDOG3qH4EYzZmhICIQCDP90Z4Cx0It6-0EhuBwT1JGJ8LbFDLa8p0lHNBLJKqA%3D%3D

Comment: Thanks. However, when i copy-paste this link to safari, it is a ads, not a video.